# Calc diff between two dates MySQL/Python

Tags: python, mysql, datetime

I would like to get the time difference between two dates in **Python 2.7**, where the dates are stored and retrieved from *MySQL*.

Running the following code:

```
import datetime
import time
from time import sleep
import MySQLdb as mdb

connection = mdb.connect('localhost', 'root', 'pwd', 'mydatabase');
cursor = connection.cursor()

TimeFormat = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'

#Insert times and type of event into database
with connection:
    #First event
    Now=datetime.datetime.now()
    Timewhen1=Now.strftime(TimeFormat)
    print "Start time", Timewhen1
    Type="1"
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO LogEvent (Timewhen, Type) VALUES (%s, %s)',(Timewhen1,Type))
    sleep(1) #Real time will be unknown, seconds to days

    #Second event
    Now=datetime.datetime.now()
    Timewhen2=Now.strftime(TimeFormat)
    print "Stop time", Timewhen2
    Type="0"
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO LogEvent (Timewhen, Type) VALUES (%s, %s)',(Timewhen2,Type))

#Get time difference
with connection: 
    cursor.execute("SELECT Timewhen FROM LogEvent ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 0,1")
    result=cursor.fetchone()

    cursor.execute("SELECT Timewhen FROM LogEvent ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1,1")
    result2=cursor.fetchone()

diff=result2-result
print "Diff", diff
```

Got the following result:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'tuple' and 'tuple'

result/result2 are in the format of `(datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 27, 22, 25, 39),)`.

Guess I'm doing something wrong with tuple/string format. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `cursor.fetchone()` returns the record which is presented as tuple of fields.
In your case, you only have one field (Timewhen), so you have a tuple with one element.

This way, to get the actual value, you need to extract this element from the tuple, so `diff = result2[0] - result[0]` should work.

Answer (score 0):

`result` and `result2` are tuples representing an entire row returned from the query. In this case, they contain a single element, as your queries contain only one column. You can extract this value by using the `[]` operator. E.g.:

```
result=cursor.fetchone()[0]
```